# BIOS update for Sony FZ31J

Tags: bios

What is the newest BIOS update for my system?

I did contact Sony, but I got no answer till now, so maybe someone here could show me where to get the latest update.

- Sony notebook, VGN-FZ31J
- Windows 7 installed
- Motherboard:

  - Manufacturer: Sony Corporation
  - Model: Vaio
  - Chipset: Intel, PM965 Rev.: C0
  - Southbridge: Intel, 82801HBM (ICH8-ME)
- BIOS:

  - Brand: Phoenix Technologies LTD
  - Version: R2110J7
  - Date: 12/21/2007

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most computer manufacturers will inform you in one way or another that unless there is a problem that will be solved by updating the BIOS, you should not update the BIOS.  Roughly translated... If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

BIOS updates rarely (if ever) add functionality that was lacked.  BIOS updates add newer processor support (seen more in desktops than laptops) and fix issues that were created or exposed in previous BIOS revisions.

Most importantly, most laptop manufacturers stop creating BIOS updates after a year or two of the release of that model laptop.  Why?  They've worked out the existing bugs in that model, they have moved on to newer designs, they don't intend to add newer processor support (to make you buy a newer laptop rather than upgrading your existing one), etc.  Rather than spend time creating BIOS updates for models they no longer make or sell, they spend their time making BIOS updates for their current models.

Sony USA doesn't recognize that model... but [Sony Germany](http://www.sony.de/support/de/product/VGN-FZ31J/updates) *does*  They do not list ANY Bios updates available for that model... which means they might not offer any.

So again... why do you want/need to update your BIOS?  Presenting the problem that requires a BIOS update might get you better results... because if you want to update your BIOS because it seems really old... that's not a very good reason.

**EDIT**  Apparently VT was disabled by Sony on purpose, but later decided to be added back in through a BIOS update, for some of the VAIO series lines.  The following laptop series had BIOS updates released: Sony decided to enable VT for the following model series lines: VGN-AW Series VGN-CS Series VGN-FW Series VGN-NS Series VGN-NW Series VGN-P Series VGN-SR Series VGN-TT Series VGN-Z Series.  Unfortunately, yours is not included in a series that had a BIOS update that enabled VT.

Comment: +1 for *If it ain't broke, don't fix it* — I hardly think there's any real problem involved here. People just like to update stuff, is all :)

Comment: @slhck, no i don`t just like to update stuff as you are saying, it is just i need to enable the VT on my laptop.It does support VT but sony did disabled it by default and didn`t gave me any way to enable it. There is a hack which could be done to enable it, but the normal way is by enabling it from Bios...and "hardly think" does not give you the right to judge if i really need the update or not ...

Comment: thanks bon gard for the answer .. i need to update my Bios to enable the VT.

Comment: See... now there is a specific reason.  Unfortunately, although Sony did appear to reverse it's position for SOME laptop models regarding VT, yours is not one of them.  Sony decided to enable VT for the following model series lines: VGN-AW Series
VGN-CS Series
VGN-FW Series
VGN-NS Series
VGN-NW Series
VGN-P Series
VGN-SR Series
VGN-TT Series
VGN-Z Series

Comment: @lebhero Well, then you need to **say that in your question**. How can we guess that you want to enable VT? If you told that right from the beginning, you would have gotten a more precise answer. It's just for your own good to be as specific as possible and **ask the right question**. Why do you think a BIOS update would enable VT for you?

Comment: @slhck Sony did make a decision to disable VT for all their Intel Core Duo laptops and such, and then later in 2009 decided to enable it for select model lines.  If he had caught wind of that, he might have assumed that his was one of the models Sony was nice about.

Comment: @slhck, hi again, well i didn`t want to get the "way it could be done with the hack found on the internet". I just want to be able to do it directly from BIOS. The BIOS Version i have does allow me to do only very basic settings. 
Almost all new BIOS versions does allow you to do more settings on your BIOS (i have another laptop from HP, where you can enable VT directly from BIOS)... 

Thanks again

Comment: @lebhero Fair enough! I'd just recommend to edit your question to be more precise. Maybe Bon Gart will update his answer accordingly with regards to VT :)

Comment: @Bon Gart, thanks for the informations. I didnt know about the Model series Line ..i thought this could be done on all Sony Vaio laptops that supports VT ..thanks for the info

Comment: @lebhero yeah, I don't know why Sony was this tight in regards to the features offered, in that they decided NOT to allow VT at first.  Not all computer manufacturers are the same, and all BIOS are specific to the model series.  Not all of them like to offer multiple features.  Just because you see a feature available in one make laptop doesn't mean all manufacturers offer that feature.

Comment: Another reason Not to buy a Sony notebook, ridiculous to block a  function of the processor.